# Почему разыменование nullptr приводит к ошибке?

Tags: c++, указатели, language-lawyer

Почему не компилируется `*nullptr`? Ведь сказано, что он приводим к любому указательному типу. Как я понимаю, это означает `operator T*`, а значит должно быть неявное преобразование и должно компилироваться. Либо быть ошибка, что непонятно к какому типу приводить.

```
struct A {
    operator int() {return 42;}
} a;

int main() {
    +a;       // OK
    *nullptr; // CE
}
```

Comment: Потому что `nullptr` определен, как не указывающий ни на один валидный объект. Даже если вы приведете его к нормальному указательному типу явно, а не оставите как `nullptr_t`... Так что он не указывает никуда, потому и не получается получить ничто :)

Comment: *"должно быть неявное преобразование"*  К какому типу? К `T *` для какого `T`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat шаблон для всех

Comment: Я не про это. В вашем конкретном случае какой `T` должен быть выбран, по вашему?

Comment: Что-то вы, похоже, в шаблонах и преобразованиях путаетесь...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat не знаю, но в таком случае разве не должна быть ошибка типа ambiguous call? А сейчас просто, мол, нет такого оператора.

Comment: @Harry можно же сделать оператор преобразования, который одновременно и шаблонной функцией является

Comment: Можно. Но у вас я такого не вижу, как и хоть какого-то преобразования `nullptr` к другому указательному типу.

Comment: @Harry я имею в виду, что я считаю, что такой оператор уже есть у типа `std::nullptr_t`. Иначе как он преобразуется в указатели?

Comment: Параметром шаблона в описываемой вами ситуации есть тип, к которому выполняется приведение...

Comment: @Harry ну вот пример короче, что я имею в виду https://godbolt.org/z/dKrKaj7vx

Comment: Приведение к любому указательному типу будет `static_cast<any_type *>(nullptr);` и работает. Разыменование не является приведением ни к какому указательному типу. Разыменование - это доступ к объекту, на который указывает указатель. При перегрузке разыменование будет `operator *`, приведение к типу казателя `operator T *`

Comment: @user7860670 вопрос в том, почему при попытке разыменования объекта не рассматриваются операторы преобразования этого объекта. Ведь среди них может быть преобразование к типу с валидным оператором *. Как это делается в случае унарного плюса в примере.

Comment: В примере есть один кандидат неявного преобразования - в `int`. Соответственно он и выбирается. Если была бы возможность преобразовать в несколько типов, или в любой тип, как в случае с nullptr, то автоматически выбрать тип, в который осуществляется преобразование, среди множества равноправных кандидатов станет невозможно. https://godbolt.org/z/aT9hMfY69

Comment: @user7860670 ок, тогда почему ошибка звучит как `indirection requires pointer operand`, а не `call to '*' is ambiguous`? Вот в вашем примере нормальная ошибка `no match for 'operator*'`, а в моём - нет. Как будто для `nullptr` есть специальное правило преобразования, а не просто оператор.

Comment: Ну это все-таки не класс, поэтому у него не может быть оператора. Скорее всего там действительно специальное правило.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat хотелось бы знать, что это, если не класс. Я думал, что класс.

Comment: `nullptr` -  литерал, значение. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy литерал типа `std::nullptr_t`. Этот тип класс или что-то другое?

Comment: `std::nullptr_t` - это встроенный тип. Для всех встроенных типов действуют специальные правила. В т.ч. для них нет отдельных, даже воображаемых (которые перечислены в 12.7 Built-in operators [over.built]), операторов приведения типов . А эти приведения выполняются по правилам изложенным в других разделах. Однако это скорее технические детали.

Comment: Это тип, не класс. Видимо, компилятор знает кое-что специальное про этот тип и специальным правилом запрещает его разыменовывать. Но разрешает приводить к указателям на другие типы.

Answer (score 3):

Рассмотрим требования для операнда встроенного унарного `*`.

[[expr.unary.op]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.unary.op#1):

> The unary * operator performs *indirection*: **the expression to which
> it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a
> function type** and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or
> function to which the expression points. ...

Но тип выражения `nullptr` не является ни указателем на объект, ни указателем на функцию. На самом деле `nullptr` имеет свой отдельный фундаментельный тип, который не может быть выражен средствами языка (как `int`), не может быть классом или указателем.

[[support.types.nullptr]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/support.types.nullptr#1):

> The type nullptr_t is a synonym for the type of a `nullptr`
> expression, and it has the characteristics described in
> [[basic.fundamental]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/basic.fundamental)
> and [[conv.ptr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/conv.ptr).
> ...

[[cstddef.syn]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/cstddef.syn):

```cpp
namespace std {
  ...
  using nullptr_t = decltype(nullptr);
  ...
}
```

[[basic.fundamental]/14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/basic.fundamental#14):

> A value of type std​::​nullptr_­t is a *null pointer constant*. ...

[[basic.fundamental]/15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/basic.fundamental#15):

> The types described in this subclause are called *fundamental types*. ...

Хорошо, но ведь мы можем привести этот тип к указательному типу. Почему не происходит неявного преобразования? — Для того чтобы неявное преобразование вообще рассматривалось, необходимо чтобы существовал тип, к которому мы хотим привести.

[[conv.general]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/conv.general#1):

> ...
>
> A standard conversion sequence will be applied to an expression if
> necessary to convert it to a required destination type.

У нас же такого типа нет (и это не может быть тип `void`, т.к. это не объектный тип).

---

Ошибки вида "*use of overloaded operator '*' is ambiguous*" не может возникнуть, т.к. она подразумевает процесс *overload resolution*, который требует наличия хотя бы одного нефундаментального типа в операндах оператора. Другими словами, если все операнды оператора не являются классами/перечислениями, то *overload resolution* происходить не будет.

---

Если сделать преобразование к объектному типу явно, то целевой тип появится и [всё будет работать](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27int+main()+%7B%0A++++//+*((void*)nullptr)%3B+//+CE,+not+an+object+type%0A++++*((int*)nullptr)%3B++//+OK,+btw+no+UB%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:42.07923003059333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1600,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+16.0.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:37.5,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+16.0.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:57.92076996940667,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4):

```cpp
int main() {
    // *((void*)nullptr); // CE, not an object type
    *((int*)nullptr);  // OK, btw no UB
}
```

Comment: `*((int*)nullptr);  //no UB` — звучит неправдоподобно.

Comment: @wololo согласен, но это скорее отдельный вопрос, чтобы тут писать. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43533262/6944845), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28482809/6944845), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38615436/6944845).